# Fitting a random curve in Python

Tags: python, scipy

Recently I have started to model pandemics as a part of personal project work. I am trying to do this in Python

One of the requirements that I have come across is how to perform curve fitting in Python. I have come across some articles which explain how to perform curve fitting for exponential or linear functions using scipy library. But in pandemic the growth curve could be either exponential, or linear

How do I perform a curve fit for any random data in Python without knowing if it will be linear or exponential ?

Comment: This is general data analysis. You need to look at the goodness of fit for any curve you generate.

Answer (score 0):

Basically any model used for prediction/extrapolate needs certain assumption(s).
For real world data as pandemic curve, I suggest you resort to more sophisticated methods such as LSTM, 1-D CNN, or Gaussian process with different combinations of kernels.